# First-order partial differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I'm working on a recurrence for a completely unrelated problem. I've modeled it as a generating function and gotten to the point:

```
a*x*(df(x,y)/dy)*(1-y) + (x-1)*f(x,y) + y^n = 0
```

where `a` and `n` are positive integers.

How can I proceed to find a solution for `f(x,y)` ? No textbooks seem to have a nice approach for this.

Comment: Maple gives me f(x, y) = (-1+y)^(1/a-1/(a*x))*(signum(-1+y)^(-(x*a+x-1)/(x*a))*(-signum(-1+y))^((x*a+x-1)/(x*a))*y^(1+n)*hypergeom([1+n, (x*a+x-1)/(x*a)], [2+n], y)/(x*a*(1+n))+_F1(x)). Good luck :)

Comment: Hmm, Wolframalpha gives something similar. I suppose it'll be a pain to get to a closed form for the recurrence from here.

Comment: This  should belong to [math.SE].